# How to find size of an image file from canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Here is a js function resizing an jpeg `image`. The original `image` is resized to `width x height` by the function. The `image.size` in `alert` returns `undefined`. Is `mainCanvas.toDataURL.length` the size of resized image file? If not, how to find the image file size after resizing?

```
    function resize(image, width, height) {
      var mainCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      mainCanvas.width = width;
      mainCanvas.height = height;
      var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
      $('#uploaded_file_hidden_file').val(mainCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")); 
      $('#file_size').val(Math.ceil(image.size/1024));
      alert(image.size);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by size you mean file size in bytes, the image element will not have a size property like `image.size`. You would need to convert the canvas into a blob and then you can get the size:

```
 // canvas.toBlob() is not well supported, so here is the polyfill just in case.
 // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Polyfill
 if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
 Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toBlob', {
  value: function (callback, type, quality) {

    var binStr = atob( this.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1] ),
        len = binStr.length,
        arr = new Uint8Array(len);

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
     arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ) );
  }
 });
}

function resize(image, width, height) {
  var mainCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  mainCanvas.width = width;
  mainCanvas.height = height;
  var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
  $('#uploaded_file_hidden_file').val(mainCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));

  // Canvas to blob so we can get size.
  mainCanvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    $('#file_size').val(Math.ceil(blob.size/1024));
    alert(blob.size);
  }, 'image/jpeg', 1);
};
```

Comment: ` alert(blob.size)` does not show anything on firefox 41.

Comment: The only problem is that the file size returned by `blob` is about half of the original size which seems too large considering the width & height are about 1/3 of the original ones.

Comment: Did a test with a file of 4.2MB original which becomes 220kb (compared with 1900kb returned by `toBlob`) after sized-down to 1024/768 and saved with jpeg quality of maximum.

Comment: Need to specify the image format which is `image/jpeg`. The default format is `png`.  Here is the code:  `mainCanvas.toBlob(function(blob){
           $('#file_size').val(Math.ceil(blob.size/1024));
            alert('blob ' + blob.size/1024);
          }, "image/jpeg");`

Comment: @user938363 you got it, specifying the format will produce the result you want. You can also pass a third parameter (float) that defines the image quality, for instance: `canvas.toBlob(function, 'image/jpeg', 0.5)` will reduce the size further.

Comment: for jpeg, default quality option is set to .92.

Answer (score 1):

To find out the final size of the file, which is of course possible, check the length of the data URI containing the image representation in the specified format

```
  const imageFileSize = Math.round(mainCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').length);
```